# LWC: how to go back to default value from <c-publish-cmp>?

Tags: lightning-web-components, js

If I press the cancel button, I want to reset the value of the combo box made using the  tag.

I tried two methods, `this.template.I tried both querySelectorAll()` and `value=null;` but it didn't work at all.

How could I  reset the value?

HTML

```html
<div class="search-combobox">
    <c-publish-cmp class="object-combobox-style" value={objectSelectValue}></c-publish-cmp>         
</div>

<lightning-button
    label="cancel"
    onclick={clearSearch}
    class="slds-m-left_x-small clear-button">
</lightning-button>
```

JS

```js
// 1) the first Way i tried

clearSearch() {
    this.template.querySelectorAll("c-publish-cmp").forEach((each) => {
      each.value = null;
    });
}

// 2) Second way i tried
 
clearSearch() {
    this.objectSelectValue = null;
}
```

Here is the code provided from

```
connectedCallback() {
    registerListener("sendNameEvent", this.setCaptureText, this);
  }

objectSelectValue;
  // This method will update the value once event is captured.
  setCaptureText(objPayload) {
    this.objectSelectValue = objPayload;
    console.log("확인", this.objectSelectValue);
    const setOptions = (output) => {
      let option = [];
      for (let key in output) {
        option.push({
          label: output[key].label,
          value: output[key].apiName,
        });
      }
      return option;
    };

    const keys = [
      "Account",
      "Opportunity",
      "Contract",
      "Order",
      "Orderitem",
   ]
 for (let i in keys) {
      if (keys[i] === objPayload) {
        this.optionsValue = setOptions(this.output[i].result.fields);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you provide the code of `c-publish-cmp`? Hard to answer without it.

Comment: Oh! I would edit my code with them!!

Comment: Is this code of `c-publish-cmp`? I don't see `@api value` variable.